# Some migration problems from vimrc to init.lua

Tags: vimrc, neovim, lua

How can I simplify the following codes in my `init.lua`?
(For "simplify" I mean that by `vim.cmd(...)` you're actually letting Lua run vimscript under the hood. But there is probably a Lua API to call instead. For example currently I learned that: `vim.cmd("set nowrap")` can be re-written to `vim.opt.wrap = false`.)

```
vim.cmd('runtime plugin/astronauta.vim')
vim.cmd('noremap! <S-Insert> <C-W>')
vim.cmd('cnoreabbrev S LspStart')
vim.g.mapleader = ' '
```

I think there will be one sentence to solve all these little problems so I combine all of them instead of ask them separately. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching.

- `vim.g.mapleader = ' '`: Simplest already.
- `vim.cmd('cnoreabbrev S LspStart')`: This has not been implemented. (read from a neovim GitHub issue)
- `vim.cmd('noremap! <S-Insert> <C-W>')`:

  ```
  vim.keymap.set('!', '<S-Insert>', '<C-W>')
  ```
- `vim.cmd('runtime plugin/astronauta.vim')` can be

  ```
  vim.api.nvim_command('runtime plugin/astronauta.vim')
  ```

Answer (score 4):

Neovim API is neither complete nor stable, and so, IMO and contrary to what other people may suggest, there's no good point (at least for now) in accepting Lua as primary configuration language. Consider also that you totally break compatibility with Vim while gaining only Lua JIT compiler to speed up execution of your loops... that you probably don't have at all.

Anyway, your best friends are `:h vim.api` and `:h api.txt`. They say what you can do now and what you can't (yet?).

So you're able to call `vim.api.nvim_set_keymap(...)` to set up a mapping without switching to VimScript engine. Also, `vim.api.nvim_command(...)` can execute that `:runtime`, though I'm almost sure that `vim.command(...)` calls it anyway, so they're practically identical. As for abbreviations, I don't see anything relevant (even no `:h mapset()` ported from Vim), so just leaving it as is.